# Use a filter inside another one in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I'd like to know if we can use a filter inside another filter, i have a table orders and inside we have another table services, i'd like to apply a filter where i only display the orders where the type of the service is type1 for example, itried the line of code below but it wont work:
`.pipe(map(orders => orders.filter(order => order.services.map(services => services.type === 'type1'))));`

```
orders = [{
    0:
id: 1
rejected: false
services: (2) [{
type: 'type1'
}, 
{
type: 'type2'
}]
    1:
id: 2
rejected: false
services: (2) [{…}, {…}]

}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly you have a `list of orders` and each list of orders contains a `list of services` and those services has a `type` property and what you need is:

> to filter only the orders of x type of service.

If the above is correct all you need to do is:

```
 var result = listOfOrders.filter( (order) => 
  order.services.some( (service) => 
      service.type === myValue));
```

Where myValue represents the type of you service you want to filter.

Comment: yees that's exactly what i was looking for, you just made my day, thank you !!